# How to update a coloumn in access 2007 based on a calculation?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Basically i have a table with one coloumn "stock" and second coloumn "stockissued". supposing 
stock coloumn has value 40 this means there are 40 items in the store and i want that whenever we type value for stockissued coloumn the previous value of stock is decremented accordingly. Like if out of 40 we write 10 in stock issued field in a form the stock value should decrement from 40 to 30.

Another important thing is that new record in a form  for stock field should have the previous decremented value updated everytime.

I need urgent help bcz working on a project!

Comment: Everyone here is working on a project. "I need urgent help" means that you either shouldn't have taken the project in the first place or that you haven't spent the time on it you should have spent. This sounds much more like a homework question. You should add the homework tag, and then post what you've tried so far that isn't working; someone here will be able to offer help.

Comment: You have a data structure issue. You should be using records in a table instead of columns within a table to track the stock numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As you have stated that you are entering the value onto a form, this is actually very easy. You could use the following code on a button click or set it to run when you update the field you typed the value into.

I am working from the assumption that you have the current value and the amount to decrease on the same form.

```
Dim UpdatedValue as string
UpdatedValue = Me.stock - Me.stockissued
Updatesql = " UPDATE YourTable SET YourTable.Stock=" & (UpdatedValue) & " " & _ 
"WHERE [YourTable]![RecordID] = Me.RecordID "

Docmd.runsql updatesql
```

Obviously you need to replace the table and field names with your own, also I added in a WHERE criteria that should ensure you dont accidentally update all the records in your table! just the one active on your current form

Comment: Are you suggesting running a SQL update statement while editing the same data in a form? That's a terrible idea, seems to me, but if you're going to do it, you need to make sure you save the record before you run the SQL statement.

Comment: Good point actually david, I usually set this type of statement to run when clicking a button that saves & closes the form and record. Its up to the original requestor where they want to use the statement